# How to remove bookmarkview under general category from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Hi In my perspective I don't want the user to see the default bookmark view as I am showing a custom view which does a similar functionality.
How can I remove it?

I tried to hide it using activities by adding the activity in the plugin.xml of plugin and disabling it in the activator but that did not help.

```xml
                <activity
                     id="com.fd.vplus.core.DefBookmarkViewactivity"
                     name="Default Bookmark view">
               </activity>
               <activityPatternBinding
                     activityId="com.fd.vplus.core.DefBookmarkViewactivity"
                     isEqualityPattern="false"
                     pattern="org.eclipse.ui/org.eclipse.ui.views.BookmarkView">
               </activityPatternBinding>
```

I tried to change the id of my view to that of default bookmark view so that it override it but that also did not help.Though this approach for some time showed mine view instead of default but now that is also not working.

Edit (Activity code in plugin Activator):

```
             IWorkbenchActivitySupport workbenchActivitySupport = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActivitySupport();
     //Enabling the activity
     IActivityManager activityManager = workbenchActivitySupport.getActivityManager();
     Set<String> enabledActivities = new HashSet<String>(); 
     String id = "com.fd.vplus.core.DefBookmarkViewActivity"; 
     if (activityManager.getActivity(id).isDefined()) { 
         enabledActivities.add(id);   
      } 
     workbenchActivitySupport.setEnabledActivityIds(enabledActivities);
```

Answer (score 1):

The owning plugin for the bookmark view is `org.eclipse.ui.ide`, you should also be use an equality pattern for this match:

```xml
 <activityPatternBinding
         activityId="com.fd.vplus.core.DefBookmarkViewactivity"
         isEqualityPattern="true"
         pattern="org.eclipse.ui.ide/org.eclipse.ui.views.BookmarkView">
 </activityPatternBinding>
```

Comment: greg-449 the code change specified did not hide the bookmark view.I have added implementation code for the activity please verify if I am missing something there.